# Resend specific order state emails e.g. order delivery shipped in shopware 6

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I'm wondering if there is any simpler solution in sending specific order state emails.

Currently i use the following code to send e.g. the "order delivery shipped" email again.

```php
$criteria = new Criteria();
$criteria->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('orderNumber', $orderNumber));
$criteria->addAssociation('orderCustomer.salutation');
$criteria->addAssociation('orderCustomer.customer');
$criteria->addAssociation('stateMachineState');
$criteria->addAssociation('deliveries.shippingMethod');
$criteria->addAssociation('deliveries.shippingOrderAddress.country');
$criteria->addAssociation('deliveries.shippingOrderAddress.countryState');
$criteria->addAssociation('salesChannel');
$criteria->addAssociation('language.locale');
$criteria->addAssociation('transactions.paymentMethod');
$criteria->addAssociation('lineItems');
$criteria->addAssociation('currency');
$criteria->addAssociation('addresses.country');
$criteria->addAssociation('addresses.countryState');

/** @var OrderEntity|null $order */
$order = $this->orderRepository->search($criteria, $context)->first();

$context = new Context(new SystemSource());
$salesChannelContext = $this->orderConverter->assembleSalesChannelContext($order, $context)->getContext();
$salesChannelContext->addExtension(
    MailSendSubscriber::MAIL_CONFIG_EXTENSION,
    new MailSendSubscriberConfig(false)
);
$event = new OrderStateMachineStateChangeEvent(
    'state_enter.order_delivery.state.shipped',
    $order,
    $salesChannelContext
);
$flowEvent = new FlowEvent('action.mail.send', new FlowState($event), [
    'recipient' => [
'data' => [],
'type' => 'default',
    ],
    'mailTemplateId' => $mailTemplateId,
]);

$this->sendMailAction->handle($flowEvent);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you don't actually want to change the state, this looks like a good solution.

If you actually needed to programmatically change the state you could use the `StateMachineRegistry` service.

```php
$transition = new Transition(OrderDeliveryDefinition::ENTITY_NAME, $orderDeliveryId, StateMachineTransitionActions::ACTION_SHIP, 'stateId');
$this->stateMachineRegistry->transition($transition, Context::createDefaultContext());
```

However if the current state is equal to the state you want to transition to, then an `UnnecessaryTransitionException` is expected to be thrown. You'd have to change the state back to a previous one before doing this and at that point your code is probably less trouble, if all you want to do is to repeat sending that mail.

Comment: Yes, i dont want to trigger a state change. Mainly because it adds superfluous entries in the "state change log".

If the solution looks good to you, i will stick to it.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to resend the mail or regenerate it? If you want to resend the mail you could use this out-of-the-box solution from FriendsOfShopware -> https://store.shopware.com/en/frosh97876597450f/mail-archive.html

[image: Resend mail]

Comment: I want to regenerate it as well. For example if you already send the tracking codes to an customer and unfortunately there is another one. So i have to regenerate the whole mail.

Answer (score 1):

You can build and send the mail with the Shopware\Core\Content\Mail\Service\MailService by yourself. But is way more code then just triggering it with a state change.

```php
        $criteria = new Criteria();
        $criteria->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('mailTemplateTypeId', self::ORDER_CONFIRMATION_MAIL_TYPE_ID));
        $criteria->addAssociation('media.media');
        $criteria->setLimit(1);

        if ($order->getSalesChannelId()) {
            $criteria->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('mail_template.salesChannels.salesChannel.id', $order->getSalesChannelId()));

            /** @var MailTemplateEntity|null $mailTemplate */
            $mailTemplate = $this->mailTemplateRepository->search($criteria, $this->context)->first();

            // Fallback if no template for the saleschannel is found
            if (null === $mailTemplate) {
                $criteria = new Criteria();
                $criteria->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('mailTemplateTypeId', self::ORDER_CONFIRMATION_MAIL_TYPE_ID));
                $criteria->addAssociation('media.media');
                $criteria->setLimit(1);

                /** @var MailTemplateEntity|null $mailTemplate */
                $mailTemplate = $this->mailTemplateRepository->search($criteria, $this->context)->first();
            }
        } else {
            /** @var MailTemplateEntity|null $mailTemplate */
            $mailTemplate = $this->mailTemplateRepository->search($criteria, $this->context)->first();
        }

        if (null === $mailTemplate) {
            return;
        }

        $data = new DataBag();
        $data->set('recipients', [
            $order->getOrderCustomer()->getEmail() => $order->getOrderCustomer()->getFirstName() . ' ' . $order->getOrderCustomer()->getLastName(),
        ]);
        $data->set('senderName', $mailTemplate->getTranslation('senderName'));
        $data->set('salesChannelId', $order->getSalesChannelId());

        $data->set('templateId', $mailTemplate->getId());
        $data->set('customFields', $mailTemplate->getCustomFields());
        $data->set('contentHtml', $mailTemplate->getTranslation('contentHtml'));
        $data->set('contentPlain', $mailTemplate->getTranslation('contentPlain'));
        $data->set('subject', $mailTemplate->getTranslation('subject'));
        $data->set('mediaIds', []);

        $attachments = [];
        if (null !== $mailTemplate->getMedia()) {
            foreach ($mailTemplate->getMedia() as $mailTemplateMedia) {
                if (null === $mailTemplateMedia->getMedia()) {
                    continue;
                }
                if (null !== $mailTemplateMedia->getLanguageId() && $mailTemplateMedia->getLanguageId() !== $order->getLanguageId()) {
                    continue;
                }

                $attachments[] = $this->mediaService->getAttachment(
                    $mailTemplateMedia->getMedia(),
                    $this->context
                );
            }
        }
        if (!empty($attachments)) {
            $data->set('binAttachments', $attachments);
        }

        try {
            if (
                null === $this->mailService->send(
                    $data->all(),
                    $this->context,
                    $this->getTemplateData($order)
                )
            ) {
                throw new \Exception('Could not render mail template');
            }

            $this->orderMailRepository->upsert([[
                'orderId'          => $order->getId(),
                'confirmationSend' => true,
            ]], $this->context);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->error(sprintf(
                'Could not send mail for order %s: %s',
                $order->getOrderNumber(),
                $e->getMessage()
            ));
        }
    }
```

Comment: OP's code is better in that regard as it will trigger the `SendMailAction` which already does all of the heavy lifting you do here.